# Creating checkboxes from MySQL database, then echo selections

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I'm am pulling out information from my database and turning the keywords into checkboxes as options.

In my MySQL I have a "keywords" column, that contains several keywords I'm turning into options. For example, keywords contains something like, "well, medium, rare, ketchup, mayo, mustard".

In my php script, I am exploding and trimming keywords to create checkboxes:

```
$i=0;
foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $keyword) {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    $chkname = "checkbox{$i}";
    $i = $i+1;
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$chkname' value='$keyword'> $keyword <br /><br />";

     }
        echo '<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Order"/> </form> </td></tr></table>';
}
```

The trouble i'm having is 
1. I don't know if this is the correct way to do this.
2. I need to figure out how to echo out a users selection. If they select "medium" and "ketchup" I need to echo those were the selections.

Here is my entire code for this page. ANY guidance, direction, or valuable insight would be appreciated more than you know. I will select the answer. Please let me know if you need anything else. I'm new to this community.

```
<?php

require("database.php"); //connect to the database

if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE id='$id' "); 
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));// Displays the error that mysql will generate if syntax is not correct.
        exit();
    }


//DYNAMIC PHP PULLING IN THE DATA AND SPITTING OUT THE RESULTS
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $picturepath = $row['picturepath'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];

    $dynamiclist = '<table align="center" width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
                        <tr height="20"></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="70%" valign="top" align="left"> <br />' . $name . ' <br /><br />$' . $price . '<br /><br />
                                 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value=" ' . $id . '"/>';


    echo $dynamiclist;

$i=0;
foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $keyword) {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    $chkname = "checkbox{$i}";
    $i = $i+1;
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$chkname' value='$keyword'> $keyword <br /><br />";

     }
        echo '<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Order"/> </form> </td></tr></table>';
}
mysqli_close($con); //close the db connection

?>

<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "checked" parameter in your  tags to make the checkbox checked by default.

To make it easier for yourself, you can use the following method of naming your checkboxes:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkboxes[]" value="'.$keyword.'" id="chk_'.$keyword.'" /><label for="chk_'.$keyword.'">'.$keyword.'</label>'."<br />\r\n"
```

If you create the checkboxes with the labels this way, people can also enable and disable the checkboxes by clicking the text behind it. By creating them all with the same name, and an array identifier behind it (the square brackets), you can access them in a simple loop in PHP after submitting the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['chkboxes'])) {
  foreach($_POST['chkboxes'] as $chkbox) {
    echo 'Checkbox checked: '.$chkbox."<br />\r\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: One more piece of advise, not related to the checkboxes: Replace

    foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $keyword) {

with

    $keywordArray = explode(',', $keywords);
    foreach($keywordArray as $keyword) {

If you do it your way, PHP will execute the explode() command every time it goes through the loop.